# Python -- consuming one generator inside various consumers

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have a generator to be consumed by various consumers. Each of the latter can take different items from the generator, so I can't just use one big for-loop to take care of all the items. What I want is to completely consume the generator. How can it be done?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
MEALS = ['Oysters', 'Consommé', 'Lamb', 'Rice', 'Sirloin','Banana', 'Pastry']

def server():
    for n in MEALS:
        yield n

def client(course, take):
    meal = []
    for _ in range(take):
        some_meal = next(course)
        meal.append(some_meal)
    return meal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #print("Available meals: ", list(MEALS))
    course = server()
    try:
        while True:
            meal = client(course, 3)
            print("First client: ", meal)
            meal = client(course, 2)
            print("Second client: ", meal)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Current output:

```
First client:  ['Oysters', 'Consommé', 'Lamb']
Second client:  ['Rice', 'Sirloin']
```

But where are the desserts??

Expected output:

```
First client:  ['Oysters', 'Consommé', 'Lamb']
Second client:  ['Rice', 'Sirloin']
First client:  ['Banana', 'Pastry']
```

**UPDATE** The accepted solution below with the added test on the returned list is OK except that I oversimplified the example code (There can be many `next` statements in `client`). What I now need is a way to return from the `client` function as soon as the first `StopIteration` is raised. So I added a follow-up question about [the best way to exit a function upon hitting the first StopIteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152578/python-exit-consumer-on-first-stopiteration).

Comment: Shouldn't you have an other line that looks like `meal = client(course, 2)` to consume the desserts ?

Comment: You're already doing it correctly. The issue is that your code can't deal with iterables shorter than you expect; `meal = client(course, 3)` fails if there are only 2 items left. You could consider using `itertools.islice` instead; `islice(myiterable, 0, 4)` will return up to 4 value, but won't fail if there are fewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second iteration of the `while` loop, the `server` generator only has 2 more items to yield, and the `client()` function will trigger the `StopIteration` exception when it tries to get 3 elements.

You'd need to handle the `StopIteration` in the `client()` function instead:

```
def client(course, take):
    meal = []
    for _ in range(take):
        try:
            some_meal = next(course)
            meal.append(some_meal)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    return meal
```

Now that a client will handle the `StopIteration`, you'll have to handle the `while` loop differently; if a `client()` doesn't return elements your `server` must've been empty:

```
while True:
    meal = client(course, 3)
    if not meal:
        break
    print("First client: ", meal)
    meal = client(course, 2)
    print("Second client: ", meal)
    if not meal:
        break
```

You are missing a few tricks from the Python standard library here. You can reimplement your `server` with `iter()`:

```
def server():
    return iter(MEALS)
```

and you could use [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to handle your client:

```
from itertools import islice

def client(course, take):
    return list(islice(course, take))
```

Comment: I see what you mean but now, how can we know that there is no more item left at the `while` loop level (`StopIteration` got swallowed by the `client`)?

Comment: @greendiod: Test if the client returns an empty list, I guess.

Comment: I need extra computations to compute the client list but I agree with you that in the simplified example, `islice` is enough. In fact, your solution with the added test on the returned list is OK except that I oversimplified the example code (There are many `next` statements in `client`). What I now need is a way to return from `client` as soon as the first StopIteration is raised.