# Python exit consumer on first StopIteration

Tags: python, exception, generator, yield

It's a follow-up to my [1 generator -- multiple consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149799/python-consuming-one-generator-inside-various-consumers) question. As `StopIteration` is the way the generator signals its exhaustion, unfortunately, I now have many exception-handling code littered all over the place in the `client` code (for every `next()` statement in the example below).

Is there a better way to exit with whatever value is built in `meal` upon hitting the first `StopIteration` exception?

```
def client(course, take):
    meal = []
    for _ in range(take):
        try:
            some_meal = next(course)
            meal.append(some_meal)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    if take % 2 == 0:
        try:
            some_meal = next(course)
            meal.append(some_meal)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    return meal
```

**UPDATE** Eventually, I ended up using 'itertools.islice' (see accepted solution below) as this function takes care of the `StopIteration` itself (see the `for`-loop equivalent implementation shown in the `itertools` doc. I prefer this solution over using `next` default second argument as it would imply checking each `meal` (still, I'd better use the latter than all the exception handling above).

Comment: Use a second argument to `next`, the default to use if there is no next item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return directly in the first exception handler:

```
def client(course, take):
    meal = []
    for _ in range(take):
        try:
            some_meal = next(course)
            meal.append(some_meal)
        except StopIteration:
            return meal
    if take % 2 == 0:
        try:
            some_meal = next(course)
            meal.append(some_meal)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    return meal
```

although I'd still use the standard library more here and not have to catch those `StopIteration` exceptions nearly as much:

```
from itertools import islice


def client(course, take):
    meal = list(islice(course, take))

    if take % 2 == 0:
        some_meal = next(course, None)
        if some_meal is not None:
            meal.append(some_meal)

    return meal
```

Comment: So, you think there is no better way than adding exception-handling everywhere?

Comment: You already had the exception handling in this method; all I did was show you where you could use `return`..

Comment: And in this case, I'd still use `islice()` anyway, because then you don't have to catch `StopIteration` at all.

Comment: My code already worked but I don't like all those `try...except` statements scattered all over the place. So your suggestion is to replace each `next` with `islice`?

Comment: @greendiod: Yes, or use `next(iterable, default)` to return a default value instead of raising `StopIteration`.

Comment: I can't see a reasonable default as I don't want add anything at all when the generator is exhausted. A `None` or an empty list would be appended and most importantly, the `client` would continue instead of returning right away (Sorry, I don't know how to reference your @name, the tab completion seems not working)

Comment: I used `None` as the default, then test for it; you could use `sentinel = object(); some_meal = next(course, sentinel); if some_meal is not sentinel:` to allow for *any* value in the iterable to be appended, including `None`. (You don't need to reference me, I am pinged always on my posts)

Comment: Your choices are either to catch the `StopIteration` to detect early that your generator is exhausted, or to ignore that the generator is empty and handle `next()` calls with a sentinel.

Comment: Ok, that will be it. I'll islice everywhere (even one by one if needed). Too bad the `islice` doc is so short.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `islice`, if I read the code correctly then it can be made even simpler:

```
def client(course, take):
    if take % 2 == 0:
        take += 1
    return list(itertools.islice(course, take))
```

Comment: Ok but no, it was just an oversimplified example. My point was that there could be many `next` statements in `client`